Mixamo character legs doesn't stay on ground after clearing keyframes
In blender I want to place a mixamo character on a different location, but everytime I do that the mixamo character legs don't stay on ground but animation still works. It looks weird. Here's what I did to get there. I first imported the character, pressed shift+right click to place to cursor location to the location I want the character then I pressed shift+s and selected "selection to cursor". After that I selected the armature and then I pressed n to open up the panels so that I can clear the keyframes for location, scale and rotation. Now when I press play, the animation stays at the location and the animation works except the characters feet doesn't stay on ground as if he's drunk his feet go all over the place lol. What do I need to do for this to not happen. Below is what the character is doing when I press play.
If I import a different character it works fine but its this character that doesn't work. Seems like the shield and stick he's holding could be the problem but I'm hoping someone has a solution.


I found a solution here, but feel free to expand on this if you have better solutions.

weird that Mixamo doesn't provide a version where the foot is still
